# Regarding implicit conversion to byte and compiler errors with byte addition

Tags: java, arrays, variables, types, operator-keyword

```
byte b = (int) 10; // Does not throw a compiler error
byte b1 = 10;
byte b2 = 20;
byte b3 = b1 + b2; // throwing Compiler error
```

Why does the compiler give an error on line no 4 and not on line no 1.

On line 1, 10 is convert to int and assign to byte b variable which implies that byte b variable may take int value.
But on line 4, it also take int value as (byte + byte = int) so it converts the value into int valued at 30 but still byte variable b3 will not accept an int value.

Comment: The compiler knows that an int with the value of 10 can always be shortened to a byte without any loss. The compiler doesn't know if the sum of 2 bytes with variable values will be able to fit in another byte. If you declare the variables as `final byte b1 = 10;` and `final byte b2 = 20;` the error will disappear because then the compiler knows that b1+b2 will always be 30 and fit another byte.